# My `GridView` breaks or is not scrollable

Tags: flutter, firebase, gridview

I am pulling my hair trying to make my grid view displays within the user's profile page, which is basically a `Column` Widget.

Either I get error regarding the "unbounceness" of the widget or other error like `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`.

If I set the `shrinkWrap` to `true` the grid is there, but unscrollable.

I tried many solution such as adding a Flexible or Expanded parent with a `mainAxisSize` to `min` for the `Column`.

My grid view code is a as follows:

```dart
/// A grid view of the user's ads
class UserAdWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId;

  const UserAdWidget({super.key, required this.userId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final query = ClassifiedAd.getQueryFromUserId(userId);

    return FirestoreQueryBuilder<ClassifiedAd>(
        query: query,
        builder: (context, snapshot, _) => Flexible(
            child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 20),
                itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // if we reached the end of the current items, get more
                  if (snapshot.hasMore && index + 1 == snapshot.docs.length) {
                    
                    snapshot.fetchMore();
                  }

                  final ad = snapshot.docs[index].data();
              
                  return ad.galleryWidget(context,
                      withAvatar: false, onTap: () {});
                })));
  }
}
```

The component code where the grid is rendered within a `Column` is as follows:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<StateModel>(builder: (context, appState, child) {
      final selfProfile = appState.loggedUser?.id == widget.user.id;

      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title:
                  Text(selfProfile ? "Votre profil" : widget.user.displayName)),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                // === User's profile widget
                UserProfileWidget(user: widget.user),

                const Divider(),

                // == Grid of user's ads
                const Text("The ads:"),
                const Text(""),

                UserAdWidget(userId: widget.user.id),
              ])));
    });
  }
```

The current code renders like so but does not scroll:

[image]

Comment: do you like to have full body scrollable?

Comment: & can you include about `galleryWidget`